# Vuejs Updating v-for by reference

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So I have a simple v-for and each item in the v-for has a @click on it

```
<result-index>
    <li v-for="(result, index) in results" @click="getReult(results[index])">
        {{ result.name }}
     </li>
 </result-index>
```

Now, my method for getResult just assigns that result to a result data:

```
methods: {
    getResult: function(result) {
        // when the child <result-update> updates this, it updates fine, but it doesn't update the v-for reference of this.
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Now I have another component that get the data for that result and display it:

```
<result-index>
    <li v-for="(result, index) in results" @click="getReult(results[index])">
         {{ result.name }}
    </li>
    <result-update v-if="result" v-model="result">
     //... here is a form to access the result and update it
    </result-update>
</result-index>
```

In my `result-update` I am updating via the `index` and `value` like so:

```
methods: {
    update(e) {
        this.$emit("input", //data here...);
    },
}

watch: {
    value: function() {
        this.form = this.value;
    },
},

created() {
    this.form = __.cloneDeep(this.value);
}
```

Which update the parent result fine (the one we used the @click on), but not the v-for reference of that result, so how can I update the v-for reference of the result when it changes in , also please note, it is not possible for me to put the  inside the v-for due to the css design of this, it needs to be seperate from the

...

Comment: try something like this: inside **getResult**, uses `this.selected= index;`, then `<result-update v-if="this.selected >= 0" v-model="results[this.selected]">`

Comment: God bless you... If you would like to create an asnwer I'll mark as best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `this.result = result`, `this.result` points to one address of the memory.

When `<result-update v-if="result" v-model="result">` receives input event then assign new value to `this.result`, it will make `this.result = newValue` (actually point to another address of the memory for newValue), so it will not change the value for `result[index]` as you expected.

Check below demo:

```js
const test = {result: []}
let value1 = ['a']
console.log('org', test)
test.result = value1 // assign with new array
console.log('Replace the whole array', test)
value1[0] = 'b' // assign new value to first element of value1
console.log('Update one item of the array', test) //test.result and value1 point to same address of the memory
```

**The solution:**

You can save the index for current `<result-index>`, then change the value by `this.results[index]`.

So adjust your codes to below then should work fine.

For the template of **component `<result-index>`**, change it to:

```
<result-index>
    <li v-for="(result, index) in results" @click="getReult(index)">
        {{ result.name }}
     </li>
</result-index>
```

For the method=**getResult** inside **component `<result-index>`**, change it to:

```
methods: {
    getResult: function(index) {
        this.selected = index;
    }
}
```

Inside the **parent component**, change the template to:

```
<result-update v-if="selected >= 0" v-model="results[selected]">
 //... here is a form to access the result and update it
</result-update>
```